# Testing which Google Play Services API is running

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing, android-geofence

When updated code containing a deprecated Android API call, it's relatively straightforward to code for each Android version. e.g.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mTonePlayer = new SoundPool.Builder().build();
    } else {
        mTonePlayer = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }
```

But what if something is deprecated in the Google Play Services API? For example `LocationServices.GeofencingAPI` was recently deprecated and should be replaced by `GeofencingClient`.

This will depend on the target device running Google Play services version 11.0.0 and isn't necessarily dependent on the Android SDK. So how can I code for both?

e.g.

```
    if (Google Play Services is below version 11.0.0) {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient etc
    } else {
        GeofencingClient gc = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient();
        gc.removeGeofences(); etc
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`checkApiAvailability()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#checkApiAvailability(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi%3C?%3E,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi%3C?%3E...)) method.

Pay attention since the method returns a task that **asynchronously** checks if specified APIs are available. If one or more aren't available, the task fails with an `AvailabilityException`.

Otherwise you can [`isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) to verify that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this device, and that the version installed on this device is no older than the one required by this client.

Comment: Ahaaah! This (the `checkApiAvailability` bit) sounds like just what I need. Thank you.